# git: List just the files modified for all stashes

Tags: git

According to the [git docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html#_options), `git stash list` will accept any of the options that you could pass to `git log`.

What I want to do is to pass the `--stat` option to `git stash list`. This works, however it seems to show the every file in the repo.

Now, I know there's a `git stash show` which will show just those files that have been changed, but I then need to manually go through and inspect each one.

Is there any way to get git to show me the list of stashes, with *just* the changes that were stashed for each one?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update for Git v2.2 onwards:**

`git stash list --stat` works.

[Things have changed](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.2.0.txt#L29-L32) since the question was asked and OP's dilemma no longer applies.  From Git v2.2 onwards, you *can* simply pass `--stat` to `git stash list` and it will behave as intuitively expected.

You can also use any of the other file listing options such as `--name-status`, `--name-only` and `--raw` available to `git log`.

The original answer below applies if you're using a version of Git prior to v2.2.

**Original answer:**

Like this I guess:

```
git stash list | while IFS=: read STASH ETC; do echo "$STASH: $ETC"; git diff --stat $STASH~..$STASH --; done
```

(Tested in Git Bash msysgit.)

`git stash show $STASH` instead of `git diff --stat $STASH~..$STASH` also worked but was unbearably slow.

Answer (score 14):

`git stash list --name-status`

Output:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on branch-name: face0ff97 Commit message

M       path/to/modified/file.cpp
A       path/to/added/file.xml
D       path/to/deleted/file.kt
stash@{1}: WIP on branch-name: 953add384 Commit message

...
```

Answer (score 5):

`git stash show -p` to show the stash in patch form is which I believe you are asking for.

For a specific stash, you could do the following: `git stash show -p stash@{x}` where x is the stash # on the stack.

Comment: Oh, sorry if my post was confusing. I want the same behavior as `git stash show` (or `git log --stat`) but without having to specify 1 by 1.

Comment: You have to create a script

Comment: Also, to just list the files for a specific stash, it would be `git stash show -p stash@{x} --name-only`

Answer (score 1):

If listing all files for one stash, e.g. the latest stash, use

> git show stash@{0} --stat